# How to automate process using MS Power Automate

Tags: excel, list, power-automate, ms-forms

I have a process give below

```
1.user fills up the form with the attached files.
2.Based on the attached file, analyst will do the analysis and send it for approval
3.Approver will approve and send it back to analyst
4.Analyst will close the case and will store the file
```

I am trying to solve it using MS Power Automate. I have setup the request using MS forms and trigger email goes to the analyst. Need so leads on how to continue the process with the excel and send it for automation. Any help will be appreciated